# Does the Unruh Effect violate observer independence in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity

Observer independence means that the physic involved is independent of the reference frame of the observers but observers can't agree on the vacuum temperature due to the the Unruh Effect, does this not violate GR's principle? If we can't agree on the energy we can't agree on curvature, correct?

Comment: Not quite. All this means is that "particle number" is not an observer-independent quantity, just as energy density ($T_{00}$) is not observer independent either. From energy consideration, roughly speaking accelerating observers need "rockets" to boost themselves so the energy budget counting isn't paradoxical either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are at rest on the surface of the earth you receive the same Unruh temperature $T = \hbar g/(2\pi c k_b)$ as if you were in a rocket accelerating with $a=1g$ (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPKj0YnKANw&t=9m26s)), so the equivalence principle is upheld. But it is not required that an accelerating and a nonaccelerating observer should see the same particle number, at least not from the quantum perspective. Relativity alone can't solve this problem.

Comment: \@Yukterez: _"If you are at rest on the surface of the earth you receive the same Unruh temperature $T$"_ For an observer on a rocket, one could say that the energy is supplied by the rocket.  But for an observer on the earth; where does the energy come from?  Or it it just thermal equilibrium and the energy is "just there"?

Comment: “-1” There is no Unruh radiation for the observer at rest on the surface of the Earth.

Comment: @A.V.S. Your downvote is not an argument but only an allegation. I quote http://scholarpedia.org/article/Unruh_effect with *"In the theory of relativity, a constant gravitational field is equivalent to a uniform acceleration"* and Matt O'Dowd at http://youtube.com/watch?v=7cj6oiFDEXc&t=9m58s *"remaining stationary in a gravitational field is equivalent to acceleration in free space; that means you, right now, are bathed in a very tiny amount of Unruh radiation"*, so downvote all you want, it doesn't change that fact - unless of course you can bring some arguments to the table.

Comment: That wasn't an argument but pointing out an error in an answer that completely invalidates it. And you have misunderstood the use of “constant gravitational field” in Scholarpedia article: it is constant in *space* also not just in time: in other words Rindler space. If M. O'Dowd is saying that phrase in the video he is just plain wrong. But for an argument have a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9606073 or http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0106111. Static gravitational field of the Earth does not have the necessary exponential stretching characteristic of either Rindler or event horizons.

Comment: In that case I'll check the articles, if O'Dowd is indeed wrong I'll correct my answer. What keywords should I search for, since you didn't provide a specific page number? I searched for "rest" and "static" (for objects at rest in a gravitational field), but didn't find anything relevant, if I have to read everything from start to end it might take a while

Comment: Now I've read Visser's whole PDF that you have linked and didn't find anything about what you've said. I'll read the other PDF later, but if you could give the specific quote it would be better.

Comment: Regarding the eventhorizon argument; in the paper "Difference between Hawking and Unruh radiation", see  https://bit.ly/385PfnS on page 600, it says *"But when we consider an observer situated on the earth, we can see a potential flaw; namely, the observer is in a local accelerated coordinate system in which there is no event horizon, but still, due to the equivalence principle, we would expect them to observe the surrounding vacuum to have a temperature. Thus, although the event horizon is invoked sometimes to explain the Hawking effect, it should not be invoked to explain the Unruh effect."*

Comment: I haven't seen your responses yesterday since you didn't @-linked me, and sorry, the paper by Visser is the wrong one, I meant that one: https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.5593 (it does have Visser as one of the authors,). But this machinery may be overkill: to see that there is *no* thermal radiation one can just compare the scales: wavelength of a typical Unruh quanta $\lambda \sim c^2/a$ for $1\,g$ of acceleration is about a light-year. Such quanta simply would not “feel” gravitational field of the Earth, so there could be no excitations for detector near Unruh temperature.

Comment: … And your last quote is from a *laser journal* and the mistake by the authors is precisely your mistake: incorrect application of EP without regard to actual length scales. Anyway, opposing quote from actual relativists who have done actual calculations [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.5671), p. 20 of arXiv pdf: *… a static  Newtonian gravitational field causes no excitations in a static detector*